# post light with a photocell sensor and GFCI wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

I installed a post light with a photocell sensor. I connected the light wires to a GFCI outlet on the load side. The GFCI trips  when i turn on the breaker. Is there a  special photo sensor that works with a GFCI outlet?

Comment: In the US, at least, any new outdoor product should work just fine with a GFCI outlet/breaker, since any new outdoor installation requires GFCI protection. If you can provide a brand/model number for the sensor or at least the post (assuming it came as a combo unit), and a clear picture (or two) of the wiring behind the sensor (if you had to install that part) and the outlet with the wires labeled (physically before the pic or digitally afterwards), that would help a lot. Also, where in the world (or specifically in the US, if that's the case) are you?

Comment: There is almost zero chance that the photocell has anything to do with this.  Somewhere a ground line (or neutral line) is not properly connected.   Start by disconnecting the light fixture and see if teh GFCI still trips.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a wiring error on your side.  Get us photos of what's going on at the lamp, and at the back of the GFCI.  What's between the two?  It will be easier to add photos if (on the same computer you posted from) you register your account (tie it to an email, Google, FB etc).